# ステータスバーへの文字数表示

Tags: emeditor

以前はステータスバーに文字数表示ができていたのですが、
今はカーソル位置の文字コードとなっております。
前のように文字数表示に戻したいのですが、
どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

→カスタマイズからステータスで設定を戻せました。

Answer (score 0):

EmEditor の [カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [ステータス] ページで、[文字数] がチェックされているかご確認ください。
[image: EmEditor [カスタマイズ] ダイアログの [ステータス] ページ]